# Why :after pseudo class works different on Microsft Edge and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, microsoft-edge

I am new to an on old project. Today came bug that the line of the tablle ( border ) is mixed with the data.

I investigated the issue and i found that old team used

```
.table-type-2 {
    margin: 15px 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;

    tbody {
        tr:last-child {

         position: relative;
         &:after {
                content: "";
                width: 100%;
                height: 8px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 8px;
                background: #bad3e0;
                left: 0;
            }

    }
  }
}
```

to detect the last tr in the table and apply border.

In microsoft edge this css code apply very precise the `:after pseudo element` and it is working great.

But in chrome the same code makes the obrder to appear not after the last tr - but on the beggining of the last tr.

I can't understant why is that.

Why the same css code looks different on these two browsers ?

Comment: The latest Chrome contains a complete reimplementation of tables, fixing lots of long standing bugs. Edge won't have the new implementation yet.

Comment: @Alohci thanks for your response. Can you please privide me link for this info that you provided ? And what you meay by reimplementation of tables by chrome ?

Comment: See [TablesNG developer notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16PFD1GtMI9Zgwu0jtPaKZJ75Q2wyZ9EZnVbBacOfiNA/edit)